# Is combining Elgamal algorithm and RSA algorithm for key generation and AES+RSA algorithm for encryption and decryption a novel approach?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, key-generation, hybrid-encryption

Key generation: Key Generation
Firstly, the RSA algorithm will be used to generate a public and a private key.

1. Generate two random prime numbers p, q.
2. Select RSA public key, P k such that gcd(P k, Φ)= 1 and 1< P k < Φ.
3. Calculate the RSA private key, Sk= P k mod Φ.
4. Calculate Elgamal public key, g= P k, private key, x= Sk.
5. Generate pEl such that P k< pEl and Sk< pEl.
6. Calculate public key, y= g
   x mod pEl such that gcd(y,ϕ(r))= 1.
7. Recalculate the RSA private key, Sk= (y-1) mod ϕ(r). 8. Assign Sk as the new
   AES secret key, k.
8. Expand k into n subkeys k1...kn
   Then the key will go through RSA encryption and the plain text will go through AES encryption.

Comment: Please fix your notation using [MathJax](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/using-mathjax-tex-on-the-cryptography-site). Take care to properly introduce all variables - e.g. step 6 currently has an $r$ showing up out of nowhere. Further consider, at the very beginning, precisely stating what you are trying to achieve - e.g. what problem you want to solve by combining these different cryptosystems. As-is this is very hard to follow.